# How writing formula that generate a random number from uniform distribution defined with its mean only?

Tags: probability

I want to write a formula that can generate random number from uniform distribution defined only of its mean $\mu$. How can I do this?

I will clarify my question with a real problem posed:

I want to generate random directed acyclic graph (DAG) which is defined with its number of nodes $v$ and shape parameter $\alpha$. Then the height and width are are generated from a uniform distribution with mean value equal to $\left(\frac{\sqrt v}{\alpha}\right)$ for height and $\alpha \times \sqrt v$ for width.

So, what I want is just a general formula for generating a random number from uniform distribution knowing only the mean, I have seen in this blog a formula that generate a random number from uniform distribution but with two parameters (mean and standard deviation).

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You should show your own work and approach to the questions that you ask. Otherwise, you aren't likely to get good answers.

Comment: "I have graph defined with its number of task $\nu$ and shape parameter 
$\alpha$" What do you mean?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean here, but a uniform random variable can't be characterized by just its mean.

Comment: Also, must your height and width be positive integer-valued, or are they continuous variables?

Comment: the height and width is equal to smallest intergral value not less than the real value generated randomly

Comment: You realize that that will cause the mean of the height and width that you actually use to produce your graphs to be higher than it should be, yes? You would be better off tailoring a discrete distribution from the start rather than fabricating one from a continuous distribution (even if on the computer you use the continuous random number generator to produce your results).

Comment: For example, you might do the following: notice that the mean of the uniform distribution on $\{ 1,\dots,n \}$ is $\frac{n+1}{2}$, and it is entirely characterized by just this one parameter $n$ (unlike a continuous uniform distribution). So just take $n$ so that $(n+1)/2$ is as close as possible to your target mean, and then generate a variable uniformly on $\{ 1,\dots,n \}$.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can come up with a way to introduce a "variability" parameter in addition to the mean, I suggest doing the following instead. Consider that a uniform distribution on $\{ 1,\dots,n \}$ has mean $(n+1)/2$ and is characterized by just one parameter. Thus, if you want a uniform distribution with mean $c$, you can approximately achieve that by using a uniform distribution on $\{ 1,\dots,r(2c-1) \}$ where $r(x)$ denotes the usual integer rounding function. This will have mean $(r(2c-1)+1)/2$, which is within $1/4$ of $c$.

Comment: if we take a=1 and b=r(2c-1),so, Height=a+r*(b-a)  .thank's

Comment: @Lamb I don't understand what you're saying. Are you talking about enforcing a minimum value other than 1 or something?